# cmd array populating empty EDIT multi dimensional

Tags: batch-file

This is giving me little headache.

I fillup an array with ip adresses and hostnames. When filling the array the corresponding element shows added to the array.

Data for sentinels.txt:

127.0.0.1 loopback
192.168.100.102 printer

When populating the array afterwards it is empty??

```
    SET /a HostCount=0
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in (Sentinels.txt) DO (
    SET ListHosts[%HostCount%]=%%A
    ECHO !HostCount! !ListHosts[%HostCount%]!
    )

    REM Check if array ListHosts is empty
    IF not "%ListHosts%"=="" (
    FOR /f %%i IN (%ListHosts%) DO (
    ECHO %%i
    )           
    )
```

Thanks in advance, I need the solution to be compatible with an array, a shown in the sample code, the existing questions here are all using a list example.

I have edited the example as good to a multi dimension.

Data for sentinels.txt:

127.0.0.1 loopback
192.168.100.102 printer

```
SET /A ElapsedCount=1
SET newline=^


SET list=Pi Ho Pa
FOR /F %%i IN ("%list: =!newline!%") DO (ECHO item is %%i in array)
pause

FOR /F %%A IN (Sentinels.txt) DO (
    SET /A HostCount+=1
    SET _local=127.0.0.1
    
    FOR /F %%i IN ("%list: =!newline!%") DO (
        SET array[!HostCount!, !i!, !ElapsedCount!] = !_local! && ECHO !_local! ARR:: !array[ !HostCount!, !i!, !ElapsedCount!]!
        SET array[!HostCount!, !i!, !ElapsedCount!] = !_local! && ECHO ARR:: !array[ !HostCount!, !i!, !ElapsedCount!]!
        SET array[!HostCount!, !i!, !ElapsedCount!] = !_local! && ECHO ARR:: !array[ !HostCount!, !i!, !ElapsedCount!]!

    )
)
```

I am not sure if the _local variable is correctly written to the array, nor do I get it out of the array.

I got tricked with exclamation/percent delayedexpansion.

Comment: Windows CMD.EXE batch file language does not have 'arrays' that work as you seem to imagine.

Comment: In no moment you increase the array value, you should use something like: set HostCount+=1 also no point in checking "%ListHosts%"=="" cause the variable doesn't seem to be created...

Comment: @RicardoBohner `set /a HostCount+=1` maybe?

Comment: @Michael Harvey exactly